# How to copy and paste two separate tables to the end of another table in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste two tables to the bottom of another table. Here is my code:

```
Sub Inv_Copy_Paste()
    Dim Inv As Worksheet
    Dim Chart As Worksheet
    Dim lr2 As Long

    Set Inv = Worksheets("Inventory Data")
    Set Chart = Worksheets("Inventory for Charts")
    lr2 = Chart.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With Inv
        .Range("A2", ("I2" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).Copy Destination:=Chart.Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
        .Range("K2", ("S2" & .Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).Copy Destination:=Chart.Range("A" & lr2 + 1)   
    End With
End Sub
```

No issues when copying one of the ranges.
When putting code together for both ranges for copying, only second range copies successfully.
Second range seems to overwrite first range.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you have to reassign a value to your last row variable before you plaste the next table

Comment: I did try making an "lr3" value and the same thing happened

Comment: Did you assign lr3 it's value before or after you pasted in the first table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of storing the last row in a variable, and then re-calculating the last row before pasting the second table, you could simply dynamically calculate the last row and use `Offset`.

I.e., change both instances of

```
Destination:=Chart.Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
```

to

```
Destination:=Chart.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```