# VBA why do I have blank rows after appending tables?

Tags: excel, vba, append

VBA newb here.

Essentially, I'm collecting weekly compliance records for week over week data.
My main issue is that I have a queried table that is dynamic and on a good week it's empty.
I would like to be able to pull the contents of this table and paste them to the first empty row below a static table that contains year to date data.

This step is an easy one to accomplish manually, but I'm looking to automate for the sake of handing this report off to my less-than-tech-savvy team members.

This question: [How to copy and paste two separate tables to the end of another table in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53054058/how-to-copy-and-paste-two-separate-tables-to-the-end-of-another-table-in-vba) has given me most of what I'm using so far. I've swapped a few of their values and declarations to be relevant to my sheet and ranges, but for the most part it's copy/paste with the listed solution for "Destination: ="

For the most part, this block does the exact thing I'm after:

(I've commented out GCC's second range, but intend to utilize it once this one's settled.)

```
Sub Inv_Copy_Paste()
    Dim TC As Worksheet
    'Dim Chart As Worksheet
    Dim lr2 As Long

    Set TC = Worksheets("TC Data Dump")
    'Set Chart = Worksheets("Inventory for Charts")
    lr2 = TC.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With TC
        .Range("O2", ("W2" & .Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).Copy Destination:=TC.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        '.Range("K2", ("S2" & .Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).Copy Destination:=Chart.Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

The one exception that I'm running into is that once the code copies populated data over, it adds a handful of blank lines below the data:

[20 Blank Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI7iC.png)

Is this something I'm overlooking in the code that's already here?
I'll grant that I *barely* understand what the code is doing in the With TC portion, so any additional context would be greatly appreciated.

**Bonus question**: Will I need a separate Sub/Worksheet when I attempt to copy *another* dynamic query table to a second static table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Dealing With Blanks

- If your data is in Excel tables, you should use their methods and properties.
- If you don't wanna, you'll need to write special, often complicated codes.
- `End(xlUp)` will only go up to the last row (cell) in the table. If there are empty or blank rows at the bottom, they will also be copied.
- The `Find` method with `xlFormulas` will go up to the last non-empty row while with `xlValues`, it will go up (further) to the last non-blank row.

**Initial**

[image]
[image]

**Result**

[image]

**Main**

```vb
Sub InvCopyPaste()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim wsTC As Worksheet: Set wsTC = wb.Sheets("TC Data Dump")
    Dim wsInv As Worksheet: Set wsInv = wb.Sheets("Inventory for Charts")
    
    Dim srg As Range, drg As Range
    
    ' Source: 'wsTC' to Destination: 'wsTC'
    Set srg = RefNonBlankRange(wsTC.Range("O2:W2"))
    If Not srg Is Nothing Then
        Set drg = RefFirstNonBlankRowRange(wsTC.Range("A2") _
            .Resize(, srg.Columns.Count)).Resize(srg.Rows.Count)
        drg.Value = srg.Value ' for only values (most efficient)
        'srg.Copy drg ' instead: for values, formulas and formats
        Debug.Print "Copied from " & srg.Address & " to " & drg.Address & "."
    End If
    
    ' Source: 'wsTC' to Destination: 'wsInv'
    Set srg = RefNonBlankRange(wsTC.Range("K2:S2"))
    If Not srg Is Nothing Then
        Set drg = RefFirstNonBlankRowRange(wsInv.Range("A2") _
            .Resize(, srg.Columns.Count)).Resize(srg.Rows.Count)
        drg.Value = srg.Value ' for only values (most efficient)
        'srg.Copy drg ' instead: for values, formulas and formats
        Debug.Print "Copied from " & srg.Address & " to " & drg.Address & "."
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**The Help**

```vb
Function RefNonBlankRange( _
    ByVal FirstRowRange As Range) _
As Range
    With FirstRowRange
        Dim cel As Range: Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If Not cel Is Nothing _
                Then Set RefNonBlankRange = .Resize(cel.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
End Function

Function RefFirstNonBlankRowRange( _
    ByVal FirstRowRange As Range) _
As Range
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = FirstRowRange.Rows(1)
    With rg
        Dim cel As Range: Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If Not cel Is Nothing Then Set rg = .Offset(cel.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    Set RefFirstNonBlankRowRange = rg
End Function
```

**`Debug.Print` Results in the *Immediate window* (`Ctrl+G`)**

```
Copied from $O$2:$W$6 to $A$4:$I$8.
Copied from $K$2:$S$6 to $A$6:$I$10.
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the row count is counting the number of lines in the first column.
-lr2 = TC.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Here.
Rather than counting the number of rows in the tablese you're trying to copy.
If you change the number 1 in this line to the column you are copying. I think its "O" which would be 15.

Then I'm afraid you'd have to redefine the lr2 for the second table or make another variable for it.
lr3 = TC.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row '11 for the k column

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I meant to comment out the lr2 variable as I'm not actually referencing it anywhere in the current code. I think my issue is coming from something in this line:
.Range("O2", ("W2" & .Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).Copy Destination:=TC.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Comment: Are your ranges overlapping?

Comment: I don't believe so. The static table range is O:W and the query table range A:I

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub oddzac()

Dim RowCount As Integer

ActiveSheet.Range("O2", Cells(Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, "W")).Copy Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 1)
ActiveSheet.Range("K2", Cells(Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, "S")).Copy Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)

End Sub
```

This more what you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry there should be a +1 in the first line aswell. My A column was empty and so didn't need it

Answer (score 0):

Another forum responded with this solution:

```
Sub TC_Copy_Paste()
Dim TC As Worksheet, RowNum As Long
'
Set TC = Worksheets("TC Data Dump")

On Error Resume Next

With TC.Range("P3").ListObject
    RowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange)
    .DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(RowNum, 9).Copy Destination:=TC.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End With

With TC.Range("AJ3").ListObject
    RowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange)
    .DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(RowNum, 9).Copy Destination:=TC.Cells(Rows.Count, 26).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End With
End Sub
```

Again, I'm not sure why this works and the other doesn't but I wanted to share the end result.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).